# Why 0 && true echo 0 in js?

Tags: javascript

As title

As I know

```
(if this part is true) && (this part will execute)

if(condition){
   (this part will execute)
}
```

0 is false, so why not echo false but 0?

[image]

Comment: `0` is falsey while `'0'` is truthy.

Comment: With `a && b`, if a falsey value is found, like 0, it returns the falsey value, not a boolean.

Answer (score 9):

Because operator `&&` return first falsey element otherwise they return last element

```
1 && 0 && false // 0
1 && 2 && 3     // 3
```

Answer (score 5):

From MDN:

> expr1 && expr2  --  Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.
>
> expr1 || expr2  --  Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true.
>
> !expr           --  Returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true.

Some expressions that can be converted to false are:

- null
- NaN
- 0
- empty string("" or '' or ``)
- undefined

**Short-circuit evaluation**

As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:

- false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false.
- true || (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to true.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript [documentation of logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) explains:

> Logical operators are typically used with `Boolean` (logical) values. When they are, they return a `Boolean` value. However, the `&&` and `||` operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-`Boolean` values, they may return a non-`Boolean` value.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript all except for `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0`, and `NaN` are `Truthy`.

In your case, `why not echo false but 0?`.

Javascript's [ToBoolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS::ToBoolean) function evaluates it to the first falsey value. i.e,

```
0 && true
=> 0

true && undefined
=> undefined

null && undefined
=> null
```

And if you need either strictly `true` or `false`, then go for `not-not` i.e, `!!`.

```
!!0 && true
=> false

!!true && undefined
=> false

!!null && undefined
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(something falsy) && (anything) will always return false.
```

Also 0 is falsy and '0' (a non empty string) is truthy

Answer (score 0):

`a && b` is equivalent to

```
if (a) {
  return b;
} else {
  return a;
}
```

So in your case `a` equals to `0`, which is falsy, therefore you get a.

Unlike other languages, JavaScript does not return `true` or `false` on `&&` and `||`, it returns the first truthy operand for a `||` operator, or the last one, and the first falsy operand for the `&&` operator, or the last one.

You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Answer (score 0):

For && operator comparing with false is always **FALSE.**

```
0 && false => 0
false && 0 => false
```

for better understanding :-
In case of && operator (always start from **left-right**), when you get the value 0 (false) it will print 0(false); if start with false it will directly print false. it won't check the second operand when get false.
but in case

```
true && 1 => 1
1 && true => true
```

as it has to check till end and ultimately give the end operand as result if won't get false.

For || operator comparing with true is always **TRUE**.

```
1 || true => 1
true || 1 => true
```

for better understanding :-
In case of || operator (always start from **left-right**), when you get the value 1 (true) it will print 1(true).
Starting with true it will directly print true. it won't check the second operand when get true.
but in case

```
false || 1 => 1
0 || true => true
```